# Java method overriding to control the behavior (python optional args-like)

Tags: java

Is the below way of using method overloading to control the behavior of `requestWork()` reasonable?

Normally, in python I would make optional arguments for passId and paperId .

```py
def requestWork(start, end, passId=None, paperId=None):
     if passId is not None: 
         # do passId stuff
     else:
         # do paperId stuff
```

Not sure what exactly is the Java equivalent to above

```
public static int doFlag = true;
public static String PASS_ID = "passID";
public static String PAPER_ID_ONE = "paperIdOne";
public static String PAPER_ID_TWO = "paperIdTwo";
public int getSomething(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    if (doFlag) {
        return requestWorkPassId(start, end, PASS_ID);
    } else {
        return requestWork(start, end PAPER_ID_ONE) + requestWork(start, end, PAPER_ID_TWO);
    }
}

public int requestWorkPassId(DateTime start, DateTime end, String passId) {
    return requestWork(start, end, passId, "");
}

public int requestWork(DateTime start, DateTime end, String paperId) {
    return requestWork(start, end, "", paperId);
}

public int requestWork(DateTime start, DateTime end, passId, paperId) {
    int output;
    if (!String.isNullOrEmpty(paperId) {
        output = SOME_EXTERNAL_API(paperId);
    } else {
        output = SOME_EXTERNAL_API_TWO(passId);
    }
    //common check for output
    return output;

}
```

Comment: Yes, I would say it's reasonable, since Java does not support optional parameters

Comment: Kotlin does support this, though

Comment: @MadProgrammer okay thank you. wasnt sure if there were some clever way of doing it besides what I was doing

Answer (score 1):

While there is no exact Java equivalent to the Python code you posted you can still somewhat realize it.

The usual way something like this is done in Java is the following:

```
public int requestWorkPassId(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    return requestWork(start, end,  "");
}

public int requestWork(DateTime start, DateTime end, String passId) {
    return requestWork(start, end, passId, "");
}

public int requestWork(DateTime start, DateTime end, String passId, String paperId) {
    int output;
    if (!String.isNullOrEmpty(paperId) {
        output = SOME_EXTERNAL_API(paperId);
    } else {
        output = SOME_EXTERNAL_API_TWO(passId);
    }
    //common check for output
    return output;
}
<!-- language: java -->
```

[Assuming d1 and d2 are DateTime objects]
This works quite simple by always passing the function call to the next function in terms of number of arguments, which is a common practice in Java:
By calling requestWork(d1, d2) you use an empty String for passId and paperId.
By calling requestWork(d1, d2, "foo") you use "foo" for passId and an empty String for paperId.
By calling requestWork(d1, d2, "", "foo") you would use an empty String for passId and "foo" for paperId (this is where Python beats Java I guess).
By calling requestWork(d1, d2, "foo", "bar") you would simply call the function containing the actual code with passId="foo" and paperId="bar".

I hope this helps & good luck for your project,
Greetings from Germany!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a more object oriented approach. You wouldn't need overloads.

---

You'd start by defining an object with all the properties your function requires:

```
class Work {
    DateTime start, end;
    String paperId = ""; // defaults to ""
    String passId = ""; // defaults to ""
}
```

Have your root function accept a `Work` object:

```
public int requestWork(Work work) {
    int output;
    if (!String.isNullOrEmpty(work.paperId) {
        output = SOME_EXTERNAL_API(work.paperId);
    } else {
        output = SOME_EXTERNAL_API_TWO(work.passId);
    }
    //common check for output
    return output;
}
```

And pass `Work` objects to the function:

```
Work work = new Work();
work.start = ...;
work.end = ...;
// paperId defaults to ""
// passId defaults to ""

requestWork(work);
```

That leviates the need for tons of overloaded methods, if you ever decided to scale up the function to account for more parameters. However, the client is not forced to specify required data.

To solve that, force the client to specify required data via a constructor:

```
class Work {
    DateTime start, end;
    String passId; // defaults to null
    String paperId; // defaults to null

    Work(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

The solution above violates multiple object oriented principles. The proper solution to this type of problem would be using the builder pattern. If you want a builder solution, let me know.